# Can't find what's wrong with this simple C code

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, scanf, gcc-warning

Its a simple tree insertion and traversal code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct tree
{
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
    int value;
};

typedef struct tree node;

void insertNode(node **root, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*root))
    {
        temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->value = val;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        *root = temp;
    }

    if(val < (*root)->value)
        insertNode(&(*root)->left, val);

    if(val >= (*root)->value)
        insertNode(&(*root)->right, val);
}

void preOrder(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {   printf(" %d",root->value);
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void inOrder(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        inOrder(root->left);
        printf(" %d",root->value);
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void postOrder(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        postOrder(root->left);
        postOrder(root->right);
        printf(" %d",root->value);
    }
}

void delTree(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        delTree(root->left);
        delTree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int val;
    char ch; ch = 'y';
    node *root;

    while(ch == 'y')
    {
        scanf("Enter the node value: %d", &val);
        insertNode(&root, val);
        scanf("Want to enter more: %c", &ch);
    }

    printf("\nInOrder traversal:\n");
    inOrder(root);
    printf("\nPreOrder traversal:\n");
    preOrder(root);
    printf("\nPostOrder traversal:\n");
    postOrder(root);

    delTree(root);
    printf("Tree Deleted.");

    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be no problem with the code and it shows no error. Though a warning is shown on compilation;

```
ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute
```

which seems to have initiated because of overlooking the return value of scanf, from [ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275116/ignoring-return-value-of-int-scanfconst-char-declared-with-attribute) .

But even on suppressing warning and compiling the executable file is not taking any input. Why is that. I am running the code on CodeBlocks IDE.

The case is same on ideone, http://ideone.com/jOnjEK .

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: Also you need to initialize root in main() and in insertNode() you are inserting infinite copies of the same value recursively trough the right nodes.

Comment: @crashmstr could you please elaborate a little

Comment: @Chetan If you compile the code in C++, you *must* cast, in C you *should not* cast. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and [Should I explicitly cast malloc()'s return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value)

Comment: @crashmstr Nice info. Thanks

Comment: @Chetan You have been harry to mark the best answer because your code contains other errors.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The code executed fine. Can you please tell me which errors, it might help

Comment: @Chetan Function insertNode has infinite recursion for the first NULL root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("Enter the node value: %d", &val);` should be

```
scanf("%d", &val);
```

and

`scanf("Want to enter more: %c", &ch);` should be

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Assuming you are intending to this

```
printf("Enter the node value:\n");
if(scanf("%d", &val) != 1)
{
printf("Integer not read \n");
break;
} 

printf("Want to enter more:\n");
if(scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1)
{
printf("character not read\n");
break;
}
```

Make a note of the space before `%c` in the `scanf()`

Comment: BTW, you should almost always test the result of `scanf`

Comment: @Gopi Thanks a ton. Could you tell me why I have to use 'printf' instead of including sentence in 'scanf'

Comment: Note: `scanf(" %c", &ch)` will only return `1`  or `EOF`.  Still like `if(scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1)`.